# Nodejs loop http requests in a function

Tags: node.js, http, express, promise, bluebird

I have been able to use bluebird to run an array of http get requests in parallel within a function that returns the responses of each requests after they have all finished. However, I would like to chain the requests in sequence to run one after another without effecting the asynchronous behavior of the promises in my current function shown below.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function buildCartWithItems(cartID,requests, cookie) {

  var promises = [];

  for (idx in requests) {

    var request = requests[idx]; // requests is an array containing the json records of each request parameter 
    request["id"] = cartID;

    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var options = {
          host: 'example.com',
          path: "/example/addToCart?"+param(request),
          headers: {'Cookie': cookie, 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
        };

        https.get(options, function (response) {
          var body = '';

          response.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
          });

          response.on('end', function() {
            console.log("jsonservicesPostRequest response: " + body);
            var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            if (parsed["STATUS"] == "success") {
              resolve(parsed.RESULT.itemGroup.id);
            } else 
              resolve("error");
          });

          response.on('error', function(exception) {
            console.log("auth error: " + exception);
            resolve(exception);
          });
        });
    }));
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Use:

```
var cart = 12345; // cart ID
var itemsParams = [];
for (idx in products) {
  var parms = {
    'guid' : prod["_id"]["GUID"],
    'count': prod["deficit"],
  };
  itemsParams.push(parms); 
}

buildCartWithItems(cart,itemsParams,newcookie).then(function(results) {
      // results -> array of all of the cart.id's
      console.log("Build Cart Results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
});
```